# Criação de novas opções para atributos Magento

Tags: php, magento

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar criar novas opções na aba "Gerenciar Opções". Ao criar um atributo, já sei como salvar os dados corretamente no banco de dados. Estou substituindo `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options`com o meu módulo para criar campos personalizados.

Meu módulo:

config.xml

```xml
<config>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                     <catalog_product_attribute_edit_tabs>Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs</catalog_product_attribute_edit_tabs>
                     <catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Options</catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>
                 </rewrite>
             </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
</config>
```

Ceicom/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Options.php

```php
class Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Options extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ceicom/attribute/options.phtml');
    }
}
```

No arquivo phtml coloquei nos campos personalizados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao que tudo indica para fazer isso precisam ser adicionadas novas colunas na tabela `eav_attribute_option`. Por exemplo, `campo_1`, `campo_2`.

Para salvar os campos adicionais eu preciso reescrever `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption()`.

Alguma dica de como fazer isso sem alterar o core, do mesmo modo que fiz acima usando `rewrite`, e como fazer o load dos dados do banco para os inputs ao editar o atributo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode reescrever o eav/entity_attribute utilizando uma outra model.

Para isso adicione no config.xml

```
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        ...
        <eav_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <entity_attribute>Seumodulo_Model_Eav_Resource_Entity_Attribute</entity_attribute>
            </rewrite>
        </eav_resource>
        ...
    </models>
    ...
</global>
```

Crie seu arquivo em

```
/app/code/local/Seumodulo/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute.php
```

e utilize a assinatura da classe assim

```
class Seumodulo_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    ...
}
```

Certifique-se de que você limpou a configuração de cache, e verifique se o módulo está aparecendo em System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output

Teste assim para ver se deu certo

```
echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute'));
```

Para salvar você pode sobreescrever os métodos que possibilitam ações antes e depois de salvar. São eles

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute::_beforeSave()
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute::_afterSave()
```

no lugar de

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption()
```

Assim você não irá precisar preocupar com o código original.

Veja alguns exemplos nos links

- [Exemplo 01](http://magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/df/d43/class_mage___eav___model___resource___attribute.php#abb8719b25a91da5d696ad6588ce8ad6b)
- [Exemplo 02](http://magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/df/d43/class_mage___eav___model___resource___attribute.php#a65307fd7120a00dd504c049f8ab2e84f)

--

Conforme a evolucão da resolução do problema nos comentários, concluí-se que o método que deve ser sobreescrito é o `catalog_entity_attribute_save_before`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, na parte do XML eu configurei correntamente, [meu xml](http://pastebin.com/SQaQv6v8), e ele me restornou `Ceicom_Swatches_Model_Eav_Resource_Entity_Attribute` ao usar `echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute'));` mas ele parece não estar pegando o codigo de dos after e before, segue a classe: http://pastebin.com/RDZhCEHv

Comment: testa extender de Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute no lugar de Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract

Comment: continua não acessando os metodos, antes quando eu usava `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, e estava dando o seguinte erro http://pastebin.com/yF3cK3ba, agora que uso `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute` o erro não aconte mas também não funciona

Comment: Esse erro ocorre pq ao extender do Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract você precisa implementar todos os métodos que a classe abstrata tem. Por isso que te falei pra extender para o Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute, mas se não funcionou ele deve fazer alguma verificação que invalida o override

Comment: Eu acho que o que eu quero fazer não tem como ser feito então ;(

Comment: Tenta copiar a classe originar toda para a sua, e ai você adiciona o seus métodos. Deve funcionar

Comment: já tentei isso, mas ele executa apenas a função do ´Core´ e não a minha

Comment: Você já tentou observar o evento "model_save_before"? Lembrando que o nome do evento pode ser prefixado para um modelo específico, por exemplo, "product_save_before" (*product* ao invés de *model*): http://magedev.com/2009/06/22/event-prefix-in-magento-models/

Comment: Verifiquei que quando ele salva ele despacha o evento `catalog_entity_attribute`, tentei criar um observer mas parece nao estar funcionando http://pastebin.com/sZ42pQar

Comment: o evento na verdade era ´catalog_entity_attribute_save_before´, eu tinha pegado apenas o prefixo sem o ´_save_before´